# Unable to properly load external script without jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to lazy load a directive within another directive based on a condition. I have a main directive and within it I have a `<script>` tag. The included directive loads properly only when jquery is present, the problem is that not all of my pages load jquery. There is also a second warning...

> synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated.

Which I should be able to suppress if I find a pure angularJs way of loading the script.

Here is my setup

```
<my-directive>
    <script ng-if="expression" src="../path" type="application/javascript"></script>
</my-directive>
```

very simple, but it only works if jquery is there to load it. I tried to load it via `$http.get()` request and then `eval()` (which I know the dangers) but that did not work.

Comment: It _may_ be because it is a script tag. Can you wrap the `script` in another element such as a `div` and apply to the `ng-if` to that?

Comment: The ng-if is working properly what is not is the evaluation of the contents of the script. When I use jquery the directive registers otherwise it just loads but nothing registers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way which leverages the `$http` approach. You can create a directive which augments your `<script>` tag for this functionality, checking for a defined `type` attribute. You could of course modify this check however you'd like. Observe the following...

```
app.directive('script', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            if (attrs.type === 'text/javascript-lazy') {
                $http.get(attrs.src).then(function(response) {
                    var code = response.data;
                    var f = new Function(code);
                    f();
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

---

```
<!-- retrieved -->
<script type="text/javascript-lazy" ng-if="true" src="script.js"></script>
<!-- not retrieved -->
<script type="text/javascript-lazy" ng-if="false" src="script.js"></script>
```

This will work inside an element wrapped directive as well.

---

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WFzhacDUrm1bRxwniaEU?p=preview) - working demo

Comment: The problem for me was that I declared the dynamically loaded directive inside `<my-directive></my-directive>`. Expecting it to work as soon as the loaded code was evaluated. What I did to solve it is that after the `f()` I `$compile()` the directive and add it to the first directive.

Comment: What I find strange though is that when I used jquery the directive was declared statically within the `<my-directive></my-directive>` and it still worked as if the directive somehow re evaluated itself.

Comment: are you appending the directives via jQuery? If you are yea you'll need to leverage `$compile` - which is normal when you mix the two. So, all solved? it was a bit tricky to follow your intentions with the dynamic directives, but hopefully all is now well @naughtyboy

Comment: Yep all is solved kinda, is there a way to make the directive re-evaluate/refresh itself? Since what I would like to do is just declare it on my first directive without having to add a new element after it loads. Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: Is there a way you could share a plunker that is replicating your problem? I'm still struggling slightly to what you're wanting to do with your directives